# Too Early to create image

Tags: python

Whenever I run the following code I get this error. I am using Python 3 might be me using code for Python 2.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python Fun", line 238, in <module>
    platform1 = PlatformSprite(g, tk.PhotoImage(file="platform1.gif"), 0, 480,100, 10)
  File "C:\Users\ ------ Com\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3394, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\ ------ Com\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3335, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('Too early to create image')
RuntimeError: Too early to create image
Press any key to continue . . .
```

*What do I do?*

```
import tkinter as tk
import random   
import time 

class Game:
    def _init_(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.title("Juniors Climb")
        self.tk.resizable(0,0)
        self.tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=1000, height=1000, highlightthickness = 0)
        self.canvas .pack()
        self.tk.update()
        self.canvas_height = 1000
        self.canvas_width = 1000
        self.bg = Photoimage(file="background.gif")
        w = self.bg.width()
        h = self.bg.height()
        for x in range(0,5):
            for y in range (0,5):
                self.canvas.create_image(xer*w, yer*h, image=self.bg, anchor='nw')
        self.sprites = []
        self.running = True

    def mainloop(self):
        while 1:
            if self.running == True:
                for sprite in self.sprites:
                    sprites.move()
            self.tk.update_idletasks()
            self.tk.update()
            time.sleeping(0.01)

class Coords:
    def _init_(self, x1=0, y1=0, x2=0, y2=0):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2

def within_x(co1, co2):
    if (co1.x1 > co2.x1 and co1.x1 < co2.x2) \
            or (co1.x2 > co2.x1 and co1.x2 < co2.x2) \
            or (co2.x1 > co1.x1 and co2.x1 < co1.x2) \
            or (co2.x2 > co1.x1 and co2.x2 < co1.x1):
        return True     
    else:
        return False

def within_y(co1, co2):
    if (co1.y1 > co2.y1 and co1.y1 < co2.y2) \
            or (co1.y2 > co2.y1 and co1.y2 < co2.y2) \
            or (co2.y1 > co1.y1 and co2.y1 < co1.y2) \
            or (co2.y2 > co1.y1 and co2.y2 < co1.y1):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def collided_left(co1, co2):
    if within_y(co1, co2):
        if co1.x1 <= co2.x2 and co1.x1 >= co2.x1:
            return True
    return False

def collided_right(co1, co2):
    if within_y(co1, co2):
        if co1.x2 >= co2.x1 and co1.x2 <= co2.x2:
            return True
    return False

def collided_top(co1, co2):
    if within_x(co1, co2):
        if co1.y1 <= co2.y2 and co1.y1 >= co2.y1:
            return True
    return False

def collided_bottom(y, co1, co2):
    if within_x(co1, co2):
        y_calc = co1.y2 + y
        if y_calc >= co2.y1 and y_calc <= co2.y2:
            return True
    return False

class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self.endgame = False
        self.coordinates = None

    def move(self):
        pass

    def coords(self):
        return self.coordinates

class PlatformSprite(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, photo_image, x, y, width, height):
        Sprite.__init__(self, game)
        self.photo_image = photo_image
        self.image = game.canvas.create_image(x, y, \
        image=self.photo_image, anchor='nw')
        self.coordinates = Coords(x, y, x + width, y + height)

class StickFigureSprite(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        Sprite.__init__(self, game)
        self.images_left = [
            PhotoImage(file="figure_L1.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure_L2.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure_L3.gif")
 ]
        self.images_right = [
            PhotoImage(file="figure_R1.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure_R2.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure_R3.gif")
 ]
        self.image = game.canvas.create_image(200, 470, \
        image=self.images_left[0], anchor='nw')
        self.x = -2
        self.y = 0
        self.current_image = 0
        self.current_image_add = 1
        self.jump_count = 0
        self.last_time = time.time()
        self.coordinates = Coords()
        game.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        game.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
        game.canvas.bind_all('<space>', self.jump)
    def turn_left(self, evt):
        if self.y == 0:
            self.x = -2
    def turn_right(self, evt):
        if self.y == 0:
            self.x = 2
    def jump(self, evt):
        if self.y == 0:
            self.y = -4
            self.jump_count = 0
    def animate(self):
        if self.x != 0 and self.y == 0:
            if time.time() - self.last_time > 0.1:
                self.last_time= time.time()
                self.current_image += self.current_image_add
                if self.current_image >= 2:
                    self.current_image_add = -1
                if self.current_image <= 0:
                    self.current_image_add = 1  
        if self.x < 0:
            if self.y != 0:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, \
                    image=self.images_left[2])
            else:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, \
                    image=self.images_left[self.current_image])
        elif self.x > 0:
            if self.y != 0:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, \
                    image=self.images_right[2])
            else:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, \
                    image=self.images_right[self.current_image])
    def coords(self):
        xy = self.game.canvas.coords(self.image)
        self.coordinates.x1 = xy[0]
        self.coordinates.y1 = xy[1]
        self.coordinates.x2 = xy[0] + 27
        self.coordinates.y2 = xy[1] + 30
        return self.coordinates

    def move(self):
        self.animate()
        if self.y < 0:
            self.jump_count += 1
            if self.jump_count > 20:
                self.y = 4
        if self.y > 0:
            self.jump_count -= 1
        co = self.coords()
        left = True
        right = True
        top = True
        bottom = True
        falling = True
        if self.y > 0 and co.y2 >= self.game.canvas_height:
            self.y = 0
            bottom = False
        elif self.y < 0 and co.y1 <= 0:
            self.y = 0
            top = False
        if self.x > 0 and co.x2 >= self.game.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0
            right = False
        elif self.x < 0 and co.x1 <= 0:
            self.x = 0
            left = False
        for sprite in self.game.sprites:
            if sprite == self:
                continue
            sprite_co = sprite.coords()
            if top and self.y < 0 and collided_top(co, sprite_co):
                self.y = -self.y
                top = False
            if bottom and self.y > 0 and collided_bottom(self.y, co, sprite_co):
                self.y = sprite_co.y1 - co.y2
                if self.y < 0:
                    self.y = 0
                bottom = False
                top = False
            if bottom and falling and self.y == 0 \
                    and co.y2 < self.game.canvas_height \
                    and collided_bottom(1, co, sprite_co):
                falling = False
            if left and self.x < 0 and collided_left(co, sprite_co):
                self.x = 0
                left = False
                if sprite.endgame:
                    self.game.running = False
            if right and self.x > 0 and collided_right(co, sprite_co):
                self.x = 0
                right = False
                if sprite.endgame:
                    self.game.running = False
        if falling and bottom and self.y == 0 \
                and co.y2 < self.game.canvas_height:
            self.y = 4
        self.game.canvas.move(self.image, self.x, self.y)

class DoorSprite(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, photo_image, x, y, width, height):
        Sprite.__init__(self, game)
        self.photo_image = photo_image
        self.image = game.canvas.create_image(x, y, \
        image=self.photo_image, anchor='nw')
        self.coordinates = Coords(x, y, x + (width / 2), y + height)
        self.endgame = True

g = Game()
platform1 = PlatformSprite(g, tk.PhotoImage(file="platform1.gif"), 0, 480, 100, 10)
platform2 = PlatformSprite(g, tk.PhotoImage(file="platform1.gif"), 150, 440, 100, 10)
platform3 = PlatformSprite(g, tk.PhotoImage(file="platform1.gif"), 300, 400, 100, 10)
platform4 = PlatformSprite(g, tk.PhotoImage(file="platform1.gif"), 300, 160, 100, 10)
platform5 = PlatformSprite(g, tk.PhotoImage(file="platform2.gif"), 175, 350, 66, 10)
platform6 = PlatformSprite(g, tk.PhotoImage(file="platform2.gif"), 50, 300, 66, 10)
platform7 = PlatformSprite(g, tk.PhotoImage(file="platform2.gif"), 170, 120, 66, 10)
platform8 = PlatformSprite(g, tk.PhotoImage(file="platform2.gif"), 45, 60, 66, 10)
platform9 = PlatformSprite(g, tk.PhotoImage(file="platform3.gif"), 170, 250, 32, 10)
platform10 = PlatformSprite(g, tk.PhotoImage(file="platform3.gif"), 230, 200, 32, 10)
g.sprites.append(platform1)
g.sprites.append(platform2)
g.sprites.append(platform3)
g.sprites.append(platform4)
g.sprites.append(platform5)
g.sprites.append(platform6)
g.sprites.append(platform7)
g.sprites.append(platform8)
g.sprites.append(platform9)
g.sprites.append(platform10)
door = DoorSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="door1.gif"), 45, 30, 40, 35)
g.sprites.append(door)
sf = StickFigureSprite(g)
g.sprites.append(sf)
g.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's pretty hard to answer this question considering there's a lot of code here. You might have a better shot at getting a good answer if you can isolate the problem to a few lines of code.

Comment: Next time, use Google to search for your question, and relevant answers on SO will appear at the top. Also, while you are composing your question, a list entitled **Questions that may already have your answer** shows up with potentially relevant questions. **Use that list** and open up the suggested questions in new tabs. This site has been around for over 7 years, if you suspect a question has already been asked, it probably has. Duplicates like this just waste time and effort.

Comment: The method to initialize a class is called `__init__` (with two leading and trailing underscores), not `_init_`. `_init_` is never called. The class `Game` has this error and that class is not the only one.

Comment: Please read and act on https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Here is the mcve for this error: "import tkinter; tkinter.PhotoImage(file='')".  This is all the code that should have been posted, even if this were not a duplicate. tk font and image functions do not work until an instance of Tk() is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is you have the Tk() object scoped specifically to the Game() class.  Try putting `root = tk.Tk()` at the very top of your python and use root/pass it around for the handle for your Tkinter work.  Also, you are using a variable called "tk" even after you imported Tkinter as tk. Consider using a different name for that variable or you could run into some problems.

Comment: Fast and Helpful. THX!

Comment: Now this pops up >>>                                                                                  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python Fun", line 239, in <module>
    platform1 = PlatformSprite(g, tk.PhotoImage(file="platform1.gif"), 0, 480, 100, 10)
  File "Python Fun", line 102, in __init__
    self.image = game.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=self.photo_image, anchor='nw')
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'canvas'
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Ok so this means you don't have a canvas to draw on.  I would recommend finding a good tutorial for Tkinter to help explain the basics of the game.  Check out this site https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter